# What's special about the double precision floating point value 1.4210854715202004e-14?

Tags: double, precision

In a library of mine, I recently saw an assertion error where the expected (double precision floating point) value is zero but the actual value is `1.4210854715202004e-14`. Googling this value I get several results, all containing this exact value.

I know it's related to the inaccuracy of the double-precision floating-point format somehow, but why am I (and many others) seeing this exact value?

Answer (score 1):

It is a throwback to non-numerical analysts using the likes of Excel and other scratchpad type tools with decimal numbers. That "magic" number represents the threshold where the next decimal digit in double precision will be too compromised by rounding errors to be meaningful. It is only really correct for adding 1!

To protect the innocent quite a few programs cut off to zero at this 15 decimal digits point and display or substitute zero instead of the actual FP value.

Most easily illustrated in Excel:

```
 A1 :  +1.4210854715202004e-14 
 A2 :  =A1/10
 A3 :  =1+A1
 A4 :  =1+A2
 A5 :  =A3-1
 A6 :  =A4-1
 A7 :  =(A4-1)
```

Adding brackets around the last expression forces it to evaluate to full FP precision and show you what is actually there. You will need to format cells Number or Scientific 16 digits displayed to see the effects of rounding rules.